# How to have different header.php based on the user logged in?

Tags: php

I’ve a created wordpress membership site using wishlist member plugin. But I want to have different `header.php` based on different logins.

Eg: Users are: Print, Web and Free

1. When Free user logs in – I want `header1.php` to load and stay till he logs out
2. When Print user logs in – I want `header2.php` to load and stay till he logs out
3. When Web user logs in – I want `header3.php` to load and stay till he logs out

If nobody has logged in the default `header.php` stays.

Please assist on how to do this.

Regards,
Raghav.

Comment: Could you show us some code that you wrote, and tell us what's not working with it?

Answer (score 2):

You  can achieve this by getting the Membership Level of the current user, and making a conditional based on this. As I do not have a license for wishlist member, this is untested.

I suppose `$member_id` to be the same value as the WordPress ID of the logged in User.

```
<?php 
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $member_id = $current_user->ID;
    include('wlmapiclass.php');
    $api = new wlmapiclass('http://yourblog.com/', 'yourAPIKey');
    $api->return_format = 'php'; // <- value can also be xml or json
    $membership = $api->get( /members/{$member_id} );
    $membership = unserialize( $membership );
    print_r( $membership ); // see in which value the actual ID or slug of the membership is stored, I cannot reproduce that..
?>
```

As TomJNowell pointed out, it would be even better to change the include to

```
get_header( $membershiplevel );
```

So you are good to go for future Membership levels.

Comment: why not just do `get_header($membershiplevel);` ? Then you'd have header.php header-Free.php header-Print.php and header-Web.php, and it'd be futureproofed if a 4th member type ever came along

Comment: @TomJNowell of course, silly me, did not think of that ;)

Comment: Where actually this script will go? in the themes function.php?

Comment: This script goes to this place where you would normally include your header file, so usually in the `page.php` or the `single.php`. You can also make it a function.

Comment: Also, I'm not understanding what is wlmapiclass.php? I'm a newbie to the wordpress and php. In the database i've got the level_ids for different levels, would that help?  Like say for Free, level_id is 12345 so can we make at as if ($level_id == 12345) {include (header1.php); } else if ($level_id == 6789) {include (header2.php); } would this do?

Comment: This is a question that is purely related to the wishlist member plugin, so you should ask there for support in this matter. The WordPress-Part, as above, should work this way.

Comment: @Raghav a copy paste answer is impossible with the information you provided, fischi has done the best he can given the provided information, but his psychic abilities appear to have failed him. If you'd like further progress, try out his first snippet and provide feedback on what happens ( including any error messages that occur, or output ), or provide further information

Comment: @Fischi: Thanks for one of the solution. will try!          #Tom: Sure will do - and let you know. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: One more thing - Have I to put these scripts into the template pages of theme that I've used?

Comment: yes, you put the code that displays the header in the place where you want to display the header